# Erro LNK2001 no Build do Projeto C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, build

Estou tentando dar Build em um projeto no Visual Studio e está aparecendo esse erro:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "class CPSock ListenSocket" (?ListenSocket@@3VCPSock@@A) TMSrv   C:\Users\Hudson\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\W2PP\Code\TMSrv\Server.obj    1   

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK1120 1 unresolved externals  TMSrv   C:\Users\Hudson\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\W2PP\Build\Debug\Server\TMSrv\run\TMSrv.exe   1
```

Alguém sabe o que pode ser ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estão faltando alguns arquivos de implementação, aparentemente da classe CPSock::ListenSocket, e de TMSrv, que pode ser uma variavel externa ou uma função.

Ou estão faltando arquivos na compilação, ou na link-edição.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda.